# How to define an array with equal value in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create a new array. Let's say

```
int[] clickNum = new int[800];
```

Then I want to do something like `clickNum = 2`, which would make all array elements starting from `clickNum[0]` to `clickNum[800]`, set to `2`. I know there's a way to do it by using a loop; but what I am after is just a function or a method to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you could use `Enumerable.Repeat` when you initialise the array:

```
int[] clickNum = Enumerable.Repeat(2, 800).ToArray();
```

It will of course be slower, but *unless you're going to be initiating literally millions of elements, it'll be fine*.

A quick benchmark on my machine showed that initialising 1,000,000 elements using a `for` loop took `2ms`, but using `Enumerable.Repeat` took `9ms`.

[This page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-array) suggests it could be up to 20x slower.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any built-in function to fill an existing array/list.
You could write a simple helper method for that if you need the operation in several places:

```
static void Fill<T>(IList<T> arrayOrList, T value)
{
    for (int i = arrayOrList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        arrayOrList[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a function you created but you do not have the time to type it. So if you want it in a single line, try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < clickNum.Length; i++, clickNum[i] = 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Array.ConvertAll should be more efficient if you are working with very large arrays and performance is a concern:

```
int[] clickNum = Array.ConvertAll(new int[800], x => x = 2);
```

And you can also use a standard LINQ Select if performance doesn't worry you:

```
int[] clickNum = new int[800].Select(x => x = 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer, I've never heard of `Array.ConvertAll` before!